# Why am I getting a list index out of range error while using face_recognition library in python?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am writing a program in python that takes input of an image having a person, compares it with images in a directory, and copies those images where face_recognition comes out to be true to another directory. It seems to work fine when there are only 10 images to be compared but when I compare the image with images nearly equal to 1000 in a directory, I get list index out of range error. Why is this happening ? The code is below

```
import face_recognition
import os
from shutil import copy

person = input("Enter the photo location of person to be found (eg. users/rishabh/my_photo.jpg) : ")
photos = input("Enter the photos folder location (eg. users/photo_folder) : ")
dest = input("Enter the location of folder to copy items into (eg. users/destination_folder) : ")
for filename in os.listdir(photos):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".JPG"): 
    print(filename)
    files = photos + '/' + filename

    known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(person)
    unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(files)
    biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
    unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

    results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
    if(results[0]==True):
        src = photos+'/'+str(filename)
        copy(src, dest)
```

[image]

Comment: You face this error when the list contains lesser items than specified. Can you check `unknown_encoding` list to see if it's empty since `()[0]` seems to return this error?

Also, I recommend using combination of `os`  and `glob` modules to identify the location instead of having users enter it manually.

Comment: ...in other words, the error is not specific to face recognition. Now, question is why you get an object that doesn't allow you to retrieve index zero. For that, you need to find out what you actually got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that there won't be any face encodings for images (images without faces).

In that case you will get empty list while doing `face_recognition.face_encodings`.

Indexing on the empty list will raise the Exception (a=[]; a[0]).

So, I have added one line to your code which checks whether list has values.

Try to run the below code and check

```
import face_recognition
import os
from shutil import copy

person = input("Enter the photo location of person to be found (eg. users/rishabh/my_photo.jpg) : ")
photos = input("Enter the photos folder location (eg. users/photo_folder) : ")
dest = input("Enter the location of folder to copy items into (eg. users/destination_folder) : ")

known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(person)
biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)

for filename in os.listdir(photos):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".JPG"):
        print(filename)
        f = os.path.join(photos, filename)

        unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(f)
        unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)
        if not len(unknown_encoding):
            print(filename, "can't be encoded")
            continue

        results = face_recognition.compare_faces(biden_encoding, unknown_encoding[0])
        if(results[0]==True):
            copy(f, dest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same error.

I found out which image was causing the issue by using:

```
print(len(face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image))
```

The above command returns the number of faces detected in the image.

The below command recognizes the first face encoding in the list:

```
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
```

And if there are no faces detected, there would be any empty list i.e, (len(face_encodings(image)=0) and the error 'list index out of range' is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because sequence script is out of range. 
conside following :

```
my_list = []
mylist[0]
```

will result in following error:

```
----> 1 my_list[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since there are no element found at given sequence range it raises the error

So following will work

```
my_list = [1,2]
my_list[0]
my_list[1]
```

But again

```
my_list[2] will raise same error
```

It seems following is returing empty list/tuple:

```
face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)
```